# Unwanted vertical space above x-axis in TikZ + pgfplots + groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spacing, groupplots

I'm using Ti*k*Z with `groupplot` to merge two plots vertically and thus I need to remove the

- lower x-axis line on the upper plot
- upper x-axis line on the lower plot.

This is achieved with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.style={}}
\begin{groupplot}[%
    group style={%
        group size=1 by 2,%
        x descriptions at=edge bottom,%
        vertical sep=0pt,%
    },%
    xmin=-1,xmax=254,
    yminorgrids,
]
%
\nextgroupplot[ymin=90,ymax=99,
    axis x line=top,
    axis y discontinuity=crunch,
]
\addplot [only marks]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
 -1 96\\
};
%
\nextgroupplot[
    ymin=0,
    ymax=50,
    axis x line=bottom,       
]
\addplot [only marks]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
    125 13\\
};
\end{groupplot}
\draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I get an unwanted vertical gap between the upper bounding box (blue line) and the upper x-axis, see:

[image]

The unwanted space disappears, if I remove the line

```
axis x line=top,
```

but then the x-axis of the upper plot reappears.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: You are missing `xmajorticks=false,` in your first plot. You might want to report that `x descriptions at=edge bottom,` should set that by default. Would be a better solution IMO.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, thank you. Adding `xmajorticks=false` makes the space disappear. I will report the problem, once I find the time :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, you have to toggle the usage of `xmajorticks` in your first plot like here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[%
        ,group style={%
            ,group size=1 by 2
            ,x descriptions at=edge bottom
            ,vertical sep=0pt
            }
        ,xmin=-1,xmax=254
        ,yminorgrids
        ]
        \nextgroupplot[%
            ,ymin=90.01,ymax=99
            ,axis x line=top
            ,axis y discontinuity=crunch
            ,xmajorticks=false
            ]
        \addplot [only marks] table[row sep=crcr]{-1 96\\};
        \nextgroupplot[%
            ,ymin=0,ymax=50
            ,axis x line=bottom     
            ]
        \addplot [only marks] table[row sep=crcr]{125 13\\};
    \end{groupplot}
    \draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]